# SSH Tunnel Issue

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to tunnel to a remote VM.

I previously used the below command:

```
ssh -N -p 22 username@1.2.3.4 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -L 127.0.0.1:8080:5.6.7.8:443
```

Something went wrong with the server at the weekend and the SA had to restore the image.

Now when I try to do this I get prompted with the following:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
username@1.2.3.4's password:
```

I don't know what this password should be and the SA isn't available.
I am able to ssh directly onto 1.2.3.4 using my public key and when on it I can ssh onto 5.6.7.8 with this command:

```
ssh -A blueboxadmin@5.6.7.8
```

Is there any way I can use this to tunnel right through. Failing that, is there anything I can setup on 1.2.3.4 that will allow me to tunnel through?

Comment: check host 5.6.7.8 for a file `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`, if they contain your public ssh key.

Comment: it's rather an authentication issue than a tunnel issue

Comment: It's not directly about programming or development. I needed this in order to do some development though. I have the issue sorted now but what should I do with this question? Delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the ssh key value pair is missing from the remote server.

You will have to copy the entry of you server ssh key (from `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file) into the remote server's `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Make sure the key is pasted in a single line. After doing this, you should be able to connect.